# Odd and even functions- a direct sum?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**
Let $V$ be the vector space of all functions $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$.
Show that $V=U \oplus W$
for $$U=\{f\ | \ f(x)=f(-x)\ \ \forall x\}, \quad W=\{f \ |\ f(x)=-f(-x) \ \ \forall x\}$$

**What I did**:

I did prove that $U \cap W$={$0$}. But proving that any function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ can be displayed as a sum of odds and evens wasn't a success. I tried saying that for $v \in V, w \in W: v=v-w+w$ and proving that $v-w \in U$ but that didn't work (that trick worked with some linear transformations we saw, but this isn't a linear transformation).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Hint:** $$f(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}+\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$$

Comment: should I use this as continuation to my path or as a new path?

Comment: @user1685224 This shows that every function is a sum of even and odds. Your work showing $U\cap W=\{0\}$ still applies.

Comment: Okay it took me about 30 minutes, to get the hint, but just to verify: What needs to be done is defining 2 functions (one equals the first factor, and the second equals the second factor), and then prove that one belongs to U, and the other to W.

Comment: @user1685224 Yes.

Comment: By the way, @AlexBecker, do you know where this idea came from? It is hard to explain how we come up with it.

Comment: I've found a great answer from Ivo Terek here -> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286284/direct-sum-of-even-and-odd-functions-make-whole-vector-space